# Al imprimir en Firefox ( CTRL + P ), se muestra la página con la tabla, pero en Chrome y Edge se muestra la página en blanco

Tags: css, mediaqueries

Tengo una tabla que puede ser impresa, al interno tiene datos de actividades diarias.

Al imprimir en Firefox obtengo el resultado querido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema llega cuando quiero hacer lo mismo desde Chrome o Edge :
[image: Imprenta en Edge]

Como ven, en los últimos dos browsers obtengo únicamente una página en blanco...

El css que tengo en el media query es el siguiente:

```
@media print {
  @print {
     size: landscape;
     margin: -110mm -100mm 0mm -100mm;
  }
  @page {
     margin: -110mm -100mm 0mm -100mm;
  }
  .no-print{
      display:none;
   }
}
```

mi estructura html (solo body) :

```
 <div class="nav no-print"></div>
 <div class="container-wide no-print">
    <div class="grid col-2">
       <div class="card"></div>
       <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-wide">
    <div class="grid col-1">
       <div class="table">
            <!-- contenido tabla -->
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener la misma visualización en los 3 navegadores web?

Comment: Jé, es simpático porque si desde Chromium (lo probé en Brave) le das a _Más Ajustes_ > _Márgenes_ > <cualquier_opción_menos_Predeterminados>, sí aparece la tabla.

Comment: @padaleiana termino de resolverlo despues de romperme la cabeza un buen rato.. al parecer a chrome no le gusta el margen en ```mm``` asique se lo di en pixel y asi al parecer le gusta mas

Comment: Podés probarlo en % también, ¿por qué no?

Answer (score 0):

Para resolverlo hice las siguientes modificas :

1. separe el `@media print` del resto de css creando asi main.css y print.css
2. los importe en el siguiente modo `<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />`  y `<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="css/print.css" media="print" />`
3. al darme cuenta que chrome y edge no acepta los margenes en *mm* : mi css quedo así :

```css
@page {
    size: landscape;
    margin: 0 5px;
 }
 *,
 *::before,
 *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   print-color-adjust: exact;
}
.no-print {
   display:none;
}
```